# EF 6 SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have searched multiple similar topics and I'm aware that I cannot have parallel transactions but I'm confused how is my code generating this error?

I'm using EF 6 with .NET 6. My issues started when I changed the transaction isolation level, but I still don't quite understand what's happening in the background.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductDTO>> GetProducts() 
{
    List<ProductDTO> result = new();
    await using var transaction = await context.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
    
    var products = await context.Products
                                .AsNoTracking()
                                . //includes
                                .ToListAsync();
    
    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        result.Add(Map(product));
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

I didn't use to have an explicit begin transaction but I added it since i wanted to get the same result as `NO LOCK`. To my knowledge, the transaction should be disposed by the end of this method, yet I'm getting this error

> SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions

while invoking that method. My context is added through DI and it's using `AddDbContextPool`. My controller is invoking the repository, so there is nothing else being called before or after that method.

Edit:
Added DI and my controller method

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
   return Ok(await productRepository.GetProducts());
}

services.AddDbContextPool<IDbContext, DbContext>(o =>
{
    o.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString, optBuilder => optBuilder.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery));
});

services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
```

Some hours after this change also started having this error on the server:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
> connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
> connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I really don't get it, connections should be managed by the framework and dbpooling, clearly it's not closing the connection or re-using it

Comment: Have you tried before doing that, two simple things: remove includes, add `AsSplitQuery()` and Automapper's `ProjectTo()`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I'm also using AsSplitQuery() and regarding the Automapper, it's actually mapperly that i'm using, so its pretty much code generated map without any circular dependencies (mentioning that since it makes things much simple)

Comment: So, you have already started transaction, and you cannot start new one on the same connection.

Comment: Can you explain it better please? The transaction should be disposed at the end of my GetProducts scope if i'm not mistaken, and i have other APIs that already had beginTransaction but with commit/rollback and without the ReadUncommited that are not having the same issue

Comment: Doesn't look like you've said anywhere which line of code it fails on.  Does it fail when you start the transaction?  When the query tries to run?  When the method completes and the transaction goes out of scope?

Comment: why do you use transaction when fetching data, especially read uncommited

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19593985/10646316) about second transaction

Comment: Are you using some kind of `WhenAll` somewhere? Is this actually your full code? Also why use `NOLOCK` it has serious data integrity implications, what do you hope to achieve by using it?

Comment: One thing to check is to ensure that the call to GetProducts and any other `async` calls using the DbContext are correctly being awaited. Also ensure that all cases where transactions are started they are disposed. (i.e. a missing `using`) This looks like it may be a case where you have another method called before this that is beginning a transaction, not awaited or that transaction isn't disposed by the time it gets to this code.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I understand the theory part, what doesnt make any sense is that's happening in my code there. My guess is that dbPool is not managing connections properly.

Charlieface No, not using WhenAll, as i said, that method is called from a controller and returns the DTO list

StevePy Since the dbContext is managed by the framework and through dbPooling, i can't really be sure what's happening in the background but all the calls are being awaited

Comment: Try to check `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT` before starting transaction. It should be `0`.

Comment: Try disabling DBContextPooling and just inject your DbContext with AddDbContext for troubleshooting.  Otherwise try to create and share a minimal repro.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yeah, im going to do that, i have a feeling that might be the cause for it, although doesn't make much sense when i remove the begin transaction from my GET, all my errors stop and everything works fine :/ (with dbpooling)

Comment: Let us know.  If that fixes it, there may be a bug in the DbContextPooling with transaction handling.

Comment: This issue might get delayed due to black friday sales, but just wanted to say i will provide information as soon as i can

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I added dbContext as transient and removed dbpooling, didn't have the "parallel transactions" error, neither pool exhaustion. I still definitely have some issues in the code and things that can be improved (db being spammed with queues at certain times) but not using dbpool seemed to have fixed most issues

Comment: You should add it as Scoped, not Transient, which AddDbContext does.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft why? I have some processes working with multi tasks and im using Task.When, so i was having issues with context already been disposed. Despite the lifetime tho, i believe EF pooling shouldnt behave the way it did